# Upload and update files in google drive via cmd

Tags: bash, csv, curl, awk, google-apps-script

Is there any script where Google drive will automatically upload, convert and update a .csv file daily?

I followed the script on the JDBC on Googles site but the server is too private and won't connect.

I have been thinking about sending the files from the command line instead as a work around, any ideas? Bash and/or curl should be used.

So far I have:[Uploading Docs to Google via cmd](https://github.com/soulseekah/bash-utils/blob/master/google-oauth2/google-oauth2.sh)

Comment: Google-Apps-Script has no access to your local files, it is a server side running language.The Google-Apps-Script tag is probably inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

http://tech.rgou.net/en/linux-2/backup-script-on-google-drive-for-linux/

To sum it up, the package grive offers you a way to mount your google drive. The rest is just editing the files as if they were on your machine.

Comment: Grive is not maintained anymore

Answer (score 0):

A python script is now available.
recursive_upload.py

It uses googleDriveAccess module.
https://github.com/HatsuneMiku/googleDriveAccess/

Answer (score 0):

There is a GitHub repository available which is used to upload files to Google drive by cli
https://github.com/svkrclg/goDrive